# Output for the matrix A is overlapped with the Matrix B

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

So,this is a code for reading matrix A and B from txt files. The following code that i found was able to read both files. However, the output for the matrix A is overlapped with the Matrix B (picture below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbRhQ.png)

```
Matrix A -----
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       99 

Matrix B -----
0       1       1
2       0       0
2       0       00
```

So, how to avoid it overlapping, please help :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    {   
        char ch;
        const char *fileName="MatrixA.txt";     // FOR MATRIX A

        ifstream file;

            file.open(fileName,ios::in);
                if(!file)
                {
                    cout<<"Error in opening file!!!"<<endl;
                    return -1; 
                }


                while (!file.eof()) 
                {
                    file >> noskipws >> ch; 
                    cout << ch; 
                }

        file.close();
    }

    {
        char ch;
        const char *fileName="MatrixB.txt";     // FOR MATRIX A

        ifstream file;

            file.open(fileName,ios::in);
                if(!file)
                {
                    cout<<"Error in opening file!!!"<<endl;
                    return -1; 
                }


                while (!file.eof()) 
                {
                    file >> noskipws >> ch; 
                    cout << ch; 
                }

        file.close();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone! Fixed it and yes i know that this is not a code for reading matrices (sorry for the misinformation). i just want it to look like one hehe so thanks again

Comment: Use `std::cout << std::endl` between both ?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger**, [e.g. `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Improve and repeat till satisfied

Comment: Btw, you don't read matrix, but just file content.

Comment: Don't copy paste code (you don't fix comment of copied code), create function instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 std::endl is not equal to newline, as it flushes

Comment: @Gladaed: which is "better" for beginners (previous (debug) output is printed before crash, which help to locate the bug).

Comment: Read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just printed a character-by-character copy of the two files, with nothing between them. Apparently "MatrixA.txt" does not have a newline at the end of the file.

You can just add a `'\n'` character after the output of the first file.

```
std::cout << '\n';
```

In a very real sense you *have not* read in two matrices, as you don't utilise any arithmetic values present in the files. If you want to do that, you will first have to come up with some *representation* of a `Matrix` in your program, and only then can you think about reading it from your files.